# Include multiple directories in Android auto backup rule?

Tags: android

I have the following Android backup rule.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <!-- /data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy/databases -->
    <include domain="database" path="." />

    <!-- /data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy/shared_prefs -->
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="com.xxx.yyy_preferences.xml" />
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="com.xxx.yyy.rate.AppRater.xml" />
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="com.xxx.yyy.billing.Affiliater.xml" />
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="com.xxx.yyy.consent.Consenter.xml" />

    <!-- /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files -->
    <include domain="external" path="recording/" />
    <include domain="external" path="attachment/" />
</full-backup-content>
```

However, I notice, by doing so, strangely only

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/recording** is backup/ restore successfully.

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/attachment** is ignored.

But, if I change the rule to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <!-- /data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy/databases -->
    <include domain="database" path="." />

    <!-- /data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy/shared_prefs -->
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="com.xxx.yyy_preferences.xml" />
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="com.xxx.yyy.rate.AppRater.xml" />
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="com.xxx.yyy.billing.Affiliater.xml" />
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="com.xxx.yyy.consent.Consenter.xml" />

    <!-- /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files -->
    <include domain="external" path="attachment/" />
    <include domain="external" path="recording/" />
</full-backup-content>
```

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/attachment** is backup/ restore successfully.

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/recording** is ignored.

Does anyone know it is so? How can I backup both attachment and recording folders?

I am testing using guidelines at

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup

**I guess we are not allow, to include multiple directories from the same domain?**

Comment: I don't have/know android, but I just read the documentation to try to help and your syntax looks good to me. Did you try to remove the "/" at the end of path ? (it should not change anything, but sometimes...). Did you try to include everything with a "." and then to exclude each sudfolder of "files/" one by one just to see ? Also, if it is an emergency problem : Did you try to implement a BackupAgent ? I saw that you can overrides OnFullBackup() to store what you want : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#ImplementingBackupAgent
I will investigate more later.

Comment: Auto backup is limited to 25mb, does the content in these files exceed this size? I am asking because "recording" folder has a suspicious name to exceed this size.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess we are not allow, to include multiple directories from the same domain?

As the docs say:

> To include multiple files, use multiple  elements.

So you can backup multiple files by using multiple `include` tags with the same domain with no problem.

By the @JAAAY comment and follow the auto-backup docs:

> The amount of data is limited to 25MB per user of your app

I think one of your two folders `attachment` or `recording` make the mount of backup data over 25MB, so it will be ignored until it's size is under 25MB.

[image]

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#xml-include-exclude

In this case, you can consider using the `exlucde` tag to exclude some files in two folders `attachment` and `recording`, which makes your backup data over limited in size.